# How to declare a restricted function pointer argument

Tags: c, function-pointers, restrict

I can declare a function taking a function pointer as argument,

```
int bar(int (* a)()) { } // this works
```

I can apply the const qualifier to this argument,

```
int bar(int (* const a)()) { } // this works
```

But when I apply the restrict qualifier to this argument, I get an error

```
int bar(int (* restrict a)()) { }

test.c:10:1: error: invalid use of ‘restrict’
 int bar(int (* restrict a)())
```

I am using cc

```
0 % gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
```

Comment: You cannot apply the `restrict` keyword to function pointer arguments (it only applies to object pointer types - [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.3/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only pointers to objects may be `restrict` qualified:

> §6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 2. Types other than pointer types whose referenced type is an object type shall not be restrict-qualified.

A function is not an object:

> §3.15.1 object
>
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

Comment: Thanks, the behavior makes sense then. I guess there is no optimization opportunity for the compiler to know, these two function pointers definitely point to different functions.